# Compare dates in VBA with offset amount

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to use the below script to compare 2 dates but only copy over the  data if the dates are more than 5 days apart. I am pretty sure my greater than equation is giving incorrect results though.

```
Sub CompareSheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim laws As Worksheet
    Set laws = Sheets("LookAhead")
    Dim galreqws As Worksheet
    Set galreqws = Sheets("Data")

    Dim RowsMaster As Integer, Rows2 As Integer
    RowsMaster = laws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows2 = galreqws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Get the number of used rows for each sheet


    With Worksheets("Data")
        For i = 2 To Rows2
        ' Loop through Sheet 2
            For j = 2 To RowsMaster
            ' Loop through the Master sheet
                If .Cells(i, 10) > laws.Cells(j + 5, 10) Then
                ' If a match is found:
                    laws.Cells(j, 7) = .Cells(i, 7)
                    ' Copy in contact info
                    Exit For
                ElseIf j = RowsMaster Then
                ' If we got to the end of the Master sheet
                    RowsMaster = RowsMaster + 1
                    ' Increment the number of rows
                    For k = 1 To 11 ' Change 3 to however many fields Sheet2 has
                        laws.Cells(RowsMaster, k) = .Cells(i, k)
                        laws.Range(laws.Cells(j + 1, 1), laws.Cells(j + 1, 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                        ' Copy the data from Sheet2 in on the bottom row of Master
                    Next
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I know this isn't directly related to your question, but just thought I'd mention that you don't have to reinitialize Screen updating back to true.  At the conclusion of the script excel will automatically turn it back to true.  Also, it's best to use proper naming conventions so it's easier to read and troubleshoot your code.  variables like "i", "j", "k" etc give very little information about what they're for, scope, or things of that nature.  Just a few thoughts =]

Answer (score 0):

```
If .Cells(i, 10) > laws.Cells(j, 10) + 5  Then
```

I don't know how your data looks like, but try this.

Comment: Unfortunately I got an error after trying it that way @Dani El:

Run-time error ‘13’:
Type mismatch

Comment: I can see that you and @Ralph have solved this problem. For making it slightly more resistant to the way you input the dates, consider using `Date` variables for storing values from cells
As for the macro closing after first row, you do have `Exit For` when match is found. That's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one or more cells contain something other than dates and therefore Excel VBA cannot compare them. Here is a slightly adjusted (portion) of your code which does a bit more error handling:

```
With Worksheets("Data")
    For i = 2 To Rows2
    ' Loop through Sheet 2
        For j = 2 To RowsMaster
        ' Loop through the Master sheet
            If IsDate(.Cells(i, 10).Value) And IsDate(laws.Cells(j, 10).Value) Then
                If CDate(.Cells(i, 10).Value) > CDate(laws.Cells(j, 10).Value + 5) Then
                ' If a match is found:
                    laws.Cells(j, 7).Value2 = .Cells(i, 7).Value2
                    ' Copy in contact info
                    Exit For
                ElseIf j = RowsMaster Then
                ' If we got to the end of the Master sheet
                    RowsMaster = RowsMaster + 1
                    ' Increment the number of rows
                    For k = 1 To 11 ' Change 3 to however many fields Sheet2 has
                        laws.Cells(RowsMaster, k).Value2 = .Cells(i, k).Value2
                        laws.Range(laws.Cells(j + 1, 1), laws.Cells(j + 1, 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                        ' Copy the data from Sheet2 in on the bottom row of Master
                    Next
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Cannot compare " & .Cells(i, 10).Value & " to " & laws.Cells(j, 10).Value & "."
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

Give it a try and let me know if this works.

Comment: The code worked fine without an error (well after I discovered a seperate issue), but unfortunately it didn't capture the difference. For example to ensure the code works, I set the laws.Cells date to be 29-Apr-16 and the .cells date to be 5/7/2016. I assume since they are both formatted as dates the formatting doesn't matter. I was able to do a subtraction calculation which told me the difference was 8 days so this should have been copied over if the calculation worked, but it didn't. Any guesses?  @Ralph

Comment: I wasn't aware that you are not storing actual dates in all cells but merely internationally formatted dates which need to be converted into actual dates. I just adjusted the code so that your cell values get converted to real dates. Now it should work as expected.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, but only when I deleted all of my other data except for this example I created. I believe the formula is closing out the loop after the very first line of my data rather than going through every line. It seemed to never get to the example data we set up unless I deleted everything else. Any ideas?

Also, what do you mean I am not storing actual dates? I can reformat my data pretty easily if that will make the code more straight forward. Thanks again. @Ralph

Comment: What is the easiest way to send you a sample file to show what the current issue is? Thanks.